# How to click anchor tag using Javascript (has no id or class)

Tags: javascript, html, css, xpath, bookmarklet

I'm in the process of creating a Javascript Bookmarklet to fill a form on a website for test purposes (I can't modify the website).

I can't seem to click on an anchor tag contained within a list item. 
So the website structure is like:

```
<Div> 
  <ul class="exampleClass"> 
    <li class="col-xs-3 col-sm-2" value="8"><a>8th</a></li>
    <li class="col-xs-3 col-sm-2" value="9"><a>9th</a></li>
    <li class="col-xs-3 col-sm-2" value="10"><a>10th</a></li>
  </ul>
</Div>
```

As you'll have noticed, the anchor tag does not have any id or class.

My Bookmarklet looks like this:

```
javascript: 

    var newVar = {
        formFill: function() {
            document.querySelectorAll("#ReasonValue")[0].value='2';
            document.find_element_by_xpath(".//a[contains(text(), '10th')]").click();
        }
    };
    newVar.formFill()
```

I just need a way to click/select one of the list items

Would very much appreciate any help.

Comment: Use click function in ul

Comment: Could you elaborate please? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be easier to just use jQuery, but I will assume that for whatever reason you cannot use jQuery, only JavaScript.

I would try something like this:

```
document.querySelector("ul.exampleClass li[value=10] a").click();
```

Comment: I got a Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute error on the Browser console with this. However, i realised it was missing apostrophes around the 10 value. So this is the working version document.querySelector("ul.exampleClass li[value='10'] a").click();

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the following procedure:

To parse the li's in the ul calss exampleClass and then parse the anchor tags of the li and then find the text 10th and click it like so:

```js
var newVar = {
  formFill: function() {
      var c = document.getElementsByClassName('exampleClass')[0].children;
      for(var i=0; i<c.length;i++)
      {
       var x = c[i].children;
       for(var j=0; j<x.length;j++)
        {
          if(x[j].innerHTML == "10th")
          {
              console.log(x[j]);
              x[j].click();
          }
        }
      }
   }
};
newVar.formFill()
```

```html
<div> 
  <ul class="exampleClass"> 
    <li class="col-xs-3 col-sm-2" value="8"><a>8th</a></li>
    <li class="col-xs-3 col-sm-2" value="9"><a>9th</a></li>
    <li class="col-xs-3 col-sm-2" value="10"><a>10th</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

But you won't be able to see anything until you add an href or something else in the a tags.

**UPDATE**

Added an alert on the click:

```js
var newVar = {
  formFill: function() {
      var c = document.getElementsByClassName('exampleClass')[0].children;
      for(var i=0; i<c.length;i++)
      {
       var x = c[i].children;
       for(var j=0; j<x.length;j++)
        {
          if(x[j].innerHTML == "10th")
          {
              console.log(x[j]);
              x[j].click();
          }
        }
      }
   }
};
newVar.formFill()
```

```html
<div> 
  <ul class="exampleClass"> 
    <li class="col-xs-3 col-sm-2" value="8"><a>8th</a></li>
    <li class="col-xs-3 col-sm-2" value="9"><a>9th</a></li>
    <li class="col-xs-3 col-sm-2" value="10"><a onclick="javascript:alert('clicked');">10th</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: "'But you won't be able to see anything until you add an href or something else in the a tags"  As mentioned in my original post, I can't modify the website (due to lack of permissions). Would this method still click the anchor tag?? I don't really want an alert. Thanks

Comment: That is fine do not modify the contents of the page look at the first code that i gave it will work just fine without modifying anything,,

Answer (score 0):

Simple example:
Selects all a-Tags inside all li-Tags with an attribute value and click them all programmatically. You can alter the value attribute in the query, so that just one item will be "clicked".

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <script src="js.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<Div>
    <ul class="exampleClass">
        <li class="col-xs-3 col-sm-2" value="8"><a onclick="console.log('clicked 8th')">8th</a></li>
        <li class="col-xs-3 col-sm-2" value="9"><a onclick="console.log('clicked 9th')">9th</a></li>
        <li class="col-xs-3 col-sm-2" value="10"><a onclick="console.log('clicked 10th')">10th</a></li>
    </ul>    
</Div>

</body>
</html>
```

Javascript:

```
var newVar = {
    formFill: function() {
        let aTags = document.querySelectorAll("li[value] a");
        let event = new Event("click", {preventDefault: false});
        aTags.forEach((atag) => {
            atag.dispatchEvent(event);
            // or without events: atag.click();
        });
    }
};

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded" , newVar.formFill);
```